# I have a problem with passing subsets to a vector. I am trying to rewrite code from Java to C ++. Any suggestions?

Tags: c++

I have a problem with passing subsets to a vector. I am trying to rewrite code from Java to C ++. Any suggestions? The program is supposed to print all possible combinations of r elements in a given array of size n.

I have a problem with passing subsets to a vector. I am trying to rewrite code from Java to C ++. Any suggestions? The program is supposed to print all possible combinations of r elements in a given array of size n.

Code

```
// The main function that prints
// all combinations of size r
// in arr[] of size n. This function
// mainly uses combinationUtil()
vector<vector<int>> getCombinations(const vector<int>& list, int r) {
    // A temporary array to store
    // all combination one by one
//    int data[r];
    vector<vector<int>> resultSet = vector<vector<int>>();

//list = u
    // Print all combination using
    // temporary array 'data[]'
//   combinationUtil(arr, data, 0, n-1, 0, r);
    return combinationUtil(list, list.size(), r, 0, vector<int>(), 0, resultSet);
}

/* arr[] ---> Input Array
data[] ---> Temporary array to
store current combination
start & end ---> Starting and
Ending indexes in arr[]
index ---> Current index in data[]
r ---> Size of a combination to be printed */
vector<vector<int>> combinationUtil(vector<int> list, int n, int r, int index, vector<int> result, int i, vector<vector<int>> resultSet) {
    // Current combination is ready
    // to be printed, print it
    if (index == r) {
        vector<int> variant = vector<int>();
        for (int j = 0; j < r; j++) {
            variant.push_back(result.at(j)); "";
        }
        resultSet.push_back(variant);
        return resultSet;
    }

    // replace index with all possible
    // elements. The condition "end-i+1 >= r-index"
    // makes sure that including one element
    // at index will make a combination with
    // remaining elements at remaining positions
    if (i >= n) {return resultSet;}

    // current is included, put next at next
    // location
    result.insert(result.begin() + index, list.at(i));
    combinationUtil(list, n, r, index + 1, result, i + 1, resultSet);

    // current is excluded, replace it with
    // next (Note that i+1 is passed, but
    // index is not changed)
    combinationUtil(list, n, r, index, result, i + 1, resultSet);
    return resultSet;
}
```

Comment: Please post the complete code including `main()` if any and with sample inputs and outputs.

Comment: What kind of problem? Please quote an exact error message and/or some input, the desired output, and the actual output.

Comment: The program does not pass subsets to this vector. I'll complete the code in a moment

Comment: everything is now

Comment: Your method of solving the posed problem is horrendously inefficient. If this is your homework, I suspect you won't be getting full credit even if you manage to fix the immediate problem. By the way, "everything" means everything, not everything except `#include` directives.

Comment: If you want to fix the error anyway, you need to use a debugger. Trace your program execution step by step, noting the value of each variable of each step. The moment the value is different from what you expect, you've found a problem.

Comment: I asked for help, not to comment on the effectiveness of the program.  I want this program to work.  Directives: #include <iostream> #include <vector> #include <algorithm> #include <iterator> #include <numeric>

Comment: @345678 the bugs in this program are result of ignoring "effectiveness" , while actually it was part of original language. and required in target language program to facilitate proper behavior  That recursion algo simply cannot work in C++ the way it is written

Comment: where is floating point output must come from even? the code doesn't do anything like that

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. ironically original code could look like that but was near-linear because Java does memoization if code formed properly (and optimization to exclude recursive calls afaik). C++ is nothing like that, it doesn't do what wasn't asked (and may dumbly do what was asked)

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie "Java does memoization". That's pure fantasy with no basis in reality.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Oh? Unless something changed since Java8, the code could have hardcoded calls to cache's methods, that's quite transparent, result in caching in simple cases,  or performing automatic if proper memoizer helper was created..

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I suppose you can create a memoizer but there is nothing to memoize. The functions are not pure and all sets of arguments are different. The result is exponentially large so it cannot run in anything close to linear time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you know both languages good enough to do translation?  E.g. your code creates a lot of copies of vectors. It's actually most used operation there. ANd this part looks suspicious, does it work right?

```
vector<vector<int>> calculate(vector<int> inputSet) {
    log(inputSet);
    vector<int> result = vector<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < inputSet.size(); i++) {
        result.push_back(inputSet.at(i));
        if (sum(result) > sum(inputSet) - sum(result)) {
            cout << i + 1 << "elementow" << endl;
            //tutaj ta funkcja zwracająca pozdbiory
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << "Nie znaleziono zbioru spelniajacego wymagania" << endl;
    return {};
}

int sum(vector<int> vector) {
    return accumulate(vector.begin(), vector.end(), 0);
}
```

`calculate` always returns an empty vector. It performs `N*3 + 2` copies of vector `inputSet` and summarily `O(3*N*(N + 1))` operations,  where N is size of that vector. You perhaps need to alias your types, e.g and pass by value:

```
    using VectorInt = vector<int>;
    using VectorInt2D = vector<vector<int>>>;


    void /*VectorInt2D*/  calculate(const VectorInt&  inputSet) {
        log(inputSet);
        int result = 0, inputSum = sum(inputSet);

    
        for (int i = 0; i < inputSet.size(); i++) {
            result += inputSet[i];
            if (result  > inputSum  - result ) {
                cout << i + 1 << "elementow" << endl;
                //tutaj ta funkcja zwracająca pozdbiory
                break;
            }
        }
        cout << "Nie znaleziono zbioru spelniajacego wymagania" << endl;
        //return {};  // what we return here?
    }
    
    int sum(const VectorInt&  vector) {
        return accumulate(vector.begin(), vector.end(), 0);
    }
```

I suspect that you don't realize that in C++ all parameters are passed by value while in Java all parameters are passed by reference. Function with signature

```
vector<vector<int>> combinationUtil(vector<int> list, int n, int r, int index, 
vector<int> result, int i, vector<vector<int>> resultSet)
```

cannot change vector passed as argument for parameter `resultSet`. Maybe  it shouldn't even try but it looks necessary for recursion.

```
vector<vector<int>> getCombinations(const vector<int>& list, int r) {
    // A temporary array to store
    // all combination one by one
//    int data[r];
    vector<vector<int>> resultSet = vector<vector<int>>();

//list = u
    // Print all combination using
    // temporary array 'data[]'
//   combinationUtil(arr, data, 0, n-1, 0, r);
    return combinationUtil(list, list.size(), r, 0, vector<int>(), 0, resultSet);
}
```

`resultSet` is not a temporary. That's a local automatic variable and it gets copied  when passed to `combinationUtil` and copied again when returned. It cannot be changed by recursive calls of `combinationUtil`. Whole thing looks flawed and seemed worked only in original language.

Comment: One way to fix that is to pass `resultSet` by reference (and remove the return value of `combinationUtil` since it is not needed any more). The other way is to stop discarding the return value of `combinationUtil` in recursive calls. Inserting `resultSet = ` before the calls should do the trick. This does not fix the excessive copying, but who am I to judge.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I think first case is preferable.. looking at other functions, it sounds more like cargo cult programming technique - functions that take referne and HAVE to return same reference. It was probably the original idea to have a function and a local variable  which would be passed through recursive calls. I avoided offering re-write as OP failed to explain what exactly his code had to do.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration:

```
vector<vector<int>>
combinationUtil(vector<int> list, int n, int r, int index, vector<int> result, int i, vector<vector<int>> resultSet); // <-- returns a vector of vectors
```

The calls:

```
result.insert(result.begin() + index, list.at(i));
combinationUtil(list, n, r, index + 1, result, i + 1, resultSet); // <-- the result is discarded

// current is excluded, replace it with
// next (Note that i+1 is passed, but
// index is not changed)
combinationUtil(list, n, r, index, result, i + 1, resultSet); // <-- the result is discarded

return resultSet;
```

If you don't need the return value, why are you returning it?

This kind of coding might work in Java, where most things are references, but not in C++. `combinationUtil` receives all arguments by value, and uses no global variables, so thee only way it can influence it surroundings is by returning a value. If you discard the returned value, you just turn the function into a (very, very expensive) no-op.

One way to fix the problem is to stop discarding the return value.

```
resultSet = combinationUtil(list, n, r, index, result, i + 1, resultSet);
```

A more efficient way is to pass `resultSet` by reference, and stop returning a value from it, since now the function works by modifying its argument.

```
void
combinationUtil(vector<int> list, int n, int r, int index, vector<int> result, int i, vector<vector<int>>& resultSet); // adjust calls accordingly
```

---

This does not address complexity of the whole solution. The combinations algorithm is exponential (n choose r to be precise) and no amount of fiddling with references can change that. The problem, as I understand it, can be solved with a much more asymptotically efficient algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated to your code.

There are many possible solutions

- Using recursion. This is a complicated and the most inefficient solution
- Using a selector array and permutations of it. This is the default standard approach.

I will show the default standard approach below.

The idea is that we have a selector array in parallel to the original data array. In this selector array, we set as much bits as the subset should be in size. And then we do all permutations for the selector array and use a value from the original array, if the corresponding selector is set.

Example for subset size of 2:

```
Base Data:  1,2,3,4

            ^ ^ ^ ^
            | | | |

Selector:   0,0,1,1  --> 3,4
            0,1,1,0  --> 2,3
            0,1,0,1  --> 2,4
            1,0,0,1  --> 1,4
            1,0,1,0  --> 1,3
            1,1,0,0  --> 1,2
```

The really simple code will then look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using MyType = int;
using Data = std::vector<int>;
using Combinations = std::vector<Data>;

Combinations getCombinations(const Data& data, const size_t subSetSize) {

    // Define the selector with the same size as the input data vector
    std::vector<bool> selector(data.size());

    // Set subSetSize elements in the selector element to true
    std::fill(selector.begin(), std::next(selector.begin(),subSetSize), true);

    // Here we will store the resulting values
    Combinations result{};

    // Here we will create the subsets. All values will be overwritten in every loop run. No need for clear or something
    Data subset(subSetSize);

    do {
        // Create the subset
        std::copy_if(data.begin(), data.end(), subset.begin(), [&, i=0u](const MyType m) mutable { return selector[i++]; });
        result.push_back(subset);

            // Create the next permutation
    } while (std::prev_permutation(selector.begin(), selector.end()));

    return result;
}

int main() {
    Data data{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 };

    for (const Data& d : getCombinations(data, 4)) {
        for (const MyType& t : d) std::cout << t << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```